# Getting "No SteamUser" error on Garry's Mod

Tags: garrys-mod

I'm getting an error on Garry's Mod that's preventing me from playing.

> Steam Error: No SteamUser.

What should I do? I've done everything the error suggested but the game still won't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open task manager (cntrl + alt + delete) or search for it via the start menu. Look for the Steam process, select it, and then click "End process".
After that open Steam/Gmod again and you should not get this error.

Comment: Still doesn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: Which steam process? There's loads.

Comment: End all Steam processes, and then without opening Steam first, launch Gmod using the desktop/start menu shortcut.

Comment: The Steam processes just re-open themselves as soon as I quit them. (Sorry for being annoying)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and most of the solutions I found online didn't work for me. But I can still fix it by:
1.Open steam
2. Run Garry mod (as adminstrator) but not in steam but run the game in its file
I hope it helps you